# Drone.io Invalid or missing image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drone.io

I'm trying to use drone to run a mysql service

Here is my .drone.yml file

```
pipeline:
 clone:
  skip_verify: true
 services:
  database:
  image: mysql:latest
```

I've try with `library/mysql` and `mysql` for the image but drone keep saying that the image is invalid or missing. Any idea anyone ? I've tried to look at the drone log but everything seem fine to me.

Comment: What version of Drone are you using?

Comment: the latest version. (docker pull drone/drone:latest)

Comment: Look like that the clone section shouldn't be in the pipeline, but outside. However after modification I got another error that say that the yml file can't be unmarshalled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things were off in your original `.drone.yml` file:
1) the `services` section needs to be configured outside the pipeline (you already got that fixed as per your comment)
2) `image` under `database` needs to be indented by two spaces

From the docs: http://docs.drone.io/mysql-example/#app-drawer

```
services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```